# Can I create an object allocated on the heap in C++ without using "new" (and implicitly pointers)?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, heap-memory

As far as I have understood, if for example I want to create a c++ object with memory allocated on the stack,I have to use  the keyword new,which therefore returns a pointer to the object which was created on the heap.
   Is there any way to create an object on the heap,and access it directly,without the use of pointers ?

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"?

Comment: If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, just stop. Think. Learn pointers. Your life will be *so* much easier if you learn to use these incredibly powerful tools instead of trying to avoid them.

Comment: Instead object_name->object_atribute;(using a pointer) Do object_name.object_attribue

Comment: In C++11 you can use `std::make_shared` and in C++14 `std::make_unique` function templates which allows you to create smart pointers to an objects without any `new`.

Comment: @user3450529 You can get that syntax with references (`Type &object_name = *new Type();`). But that's not really different in any way relevant to this question, it's just a minor syntactic difference. A reference is still a pointer under the hood.

Comment: @delnan - Not quite - cannot have a null reference

Comment: @EdHeal That is *exactly* why I added "in any way relevant to this question". Note that `new` does not return NULL (unless explicitly asked to via `nothrow`).

Comment: You can have a null pointer - not a null reference. This distinction can be useful.

Comment: @EdHeal *I know that*. But it's not relevant to OP's apparent pointer phobia, that references prevent NULL is no reason to look for a way to spell heap allocation without `new`.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you actualy after.... Is it references or smart pointers? You should perhaps add some code to the question, showing what you have now, and explain how you would like it to be instead.

Comment: "I want to do X without using Y". In your case, X is heap allocation, and Y is pointers. Another example: X is driving a nail, Y is a hammer. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: You write "with memory allocated on the stack" -- don't you mean "with memory allocated on the heap"?

Comment: _We'll_ decide when this question is closed.

Comment: That "references are pointers under the hood" is an implementation detail. The language says no such thing. You display a consistent inability to work within the language's abstractions, @delnan.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd rather say I display a consistent ability to go beyond a single language and give alternative formulations for language semantics ;-) I assure you I can and do work with the language's abstraction, should you choose to browse through my writings on this site you'll fine plenty of examples. But I can also work with a large number of abstractions above, below and besides the abstractions of any particular programming language, an extremely useful skill in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to create an object on the heap,and access it directly,without the use of pointers ?

Let's start by saying that the C++ standard does not have a notion of *heap* and *stack* because C++ can be compiled on machines that does not have an *heap*. So, from now on I'm just gonna assume you mean to *dynamically allocate* memory.

You can avoid using `new` to dynamically allocate memory by using `malloc` (and similar C functions) but I wouldn't recommend this, especially because you would still use pointers.

The other alternative is to use an [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) together with [`std::make_unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) and generate a dynamically allocated resource and just bind a reference to it:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique(...);
auto& ref = *ptr;
```

and then you'll be able to avoid using pointer semantic. But really: just use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) and be done with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "machines that does not have an *heap*"? A heap is just any region for dynamic memory allocation; if you can "*dynamically allocate* memory" you have a heap. Unlike to "stack", the term "heap" does not imply any implementation details or interface restrictions. Edit: Did you perhaps mean "not have a stack"? That would make more sense, but look out of place in the context.

Comment: @delnan "A heap is just any region for dynamic memory allocation; if you can "dynamically allocate memory" you have a heap." -- Unfortunately the C++ standard does not mention any *heap* or define what that is. And even the *stack* is only mentioned when talking about "*stack unwinding*" and the `std::stack` class and never *defined*. So yeah, C++ does not have the same notion of *stack* and *heap* as you do.

Comment: The C++ standard is not a comprehensive encyclopedia of programming jargon. I think the term used in the standard is "free store", but that means *exactly* what is meant by "heap". Insisting that the former term is used, that the semantically *identical* and more cross-language term "heap" is wrong, is plain silly. Do you always call a car an *automobile*?

Comment: @delnan, The reason they use "free store" or "dynamically allocated memory" is because they tend to talk in a more abstract way. As long as the implementer correctly implements the behavior of both, nobody (not even me and/or the language specification) care what implementation is used for it to work. So yeah, it might be pedantic, but I like my answers to be as precise as possible. Also, please note that I've just made a clarification on the term's usage, I haven't criticized it. Best regards.

Comment: "Stack"/"heap" are outmoded and inaccurate, @delnan. There is no reason to propagate this nonsense when we can talk sensibly about storage durations and object lifetimes, instead. Thanks.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm a huge fan of lifetime reasoning, it's a major part of the appeal Rust has to me. Being a compilers guy, I'm also a huge fan of redirecting allocations without affecting semantics. But I consider "stack" and "heap" merely anachronistic terms for different kinds of storage locations, not indicators of a specific (now outdated) implementation strategy. Of course, sometimes people read too much into them, but I don't see evidence of them being harmful.